# How to dynamically download a file from an external webpage that will only fire the download popup 5 seconds after the page loads?

Tags: php

I have to dynamically download a pdf file from an external webpage.
The download ('save as') popup will only appear 5 seconds after the page loads.
How can I download the pdf file from an external website using PHP?

```
$pdf = file_get_contents($response['url']);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($pdf);
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

This code will obviously get the external web page HTML, which is not the intended output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to parse the download filename from the HTML page. Can you share that link? Somewhere in the HTML (or a linked JS file) is the true URL to the PDF document you want to capture.

Comment: Hi there. You are right. I solved the problem accessing directly the URL. Thks a lot.